# When is it correct to use null given that there is Optional?

Tags: java, null, option-type

Java has an `Optional` type, which alleviates a lot of the pain `null` causes. Is there any valid use cases for `null` anymore? Why would one use `null` but not `Optional`?

One possible venue is perhaps performance. `null` probably is faster than an `Optional`.

Comment: Part of the problem is that an `Optional` can itself be null

Comment: [Optional is intended for return types only.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327957/should-java-8-getters-return-optional-type/26328555#26328555)  It should never be used for property types or argument types.

Comment: "which alleviates a lot of the pain null causes" [citation needed]

Comment: Performance is irrelevant. You can use `null` anywhere you want. `Optional` for return values has an advantage for chained operations such as you use with streams.

Comment: Related: [Why should Java 8's Optional not be used in arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31922866/why-should-java-8s-optional-not-be-used-in-arguments). [Should I use Java8/Guava Optional for every method that may return null?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18681243/should-i-use-java8-guava-optional-for-every-method-that-may-return-null).

Answer (score 3):

`Optional` object's typical use case is for method's `return` types only.

Also, it is NOT a good practice to use `Optional` as method arguments or constructor arguments because **we can't enforce non-null optional objects** i.e., the `Optional` object itself can be `null`. In other words, even if you pass an `Optional` object as method parameter as we can't guarantee that the `Optional` object itself is NOT null, you might still end up with a `null` check. I suggest you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31922866/why-should-java-8s-optional-not-be-used-in-arguments) on a detailed discussion on this subject.

The other point is that Java's **`Optional` is NOT `Serializable`**, so you can't use `Optional` on the variables/fields whichever require Serialization. You can refer more on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24547673/why-java-util-optional-is-not-serializable-how-to-serialize-the-object-with-suc).

So, the important point is that **we still need `null` references wherever `Optional` does not make sense**.

Comment: They argue that rather than accepting an `Optional` argument, for the convenience of the caller you should overload your method: one version requires a non-null argument and one doesn’t have that parameter at all.